# Как сделать загрузку элементов при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Где я ошибаюсь? Делаю подгрузку элементов при прокрутке. По началу все отрабатывает нормально когда scroll в конце а потом начинает все подгружается с середины. Как-то не корректно. Размер блока моего width: 950px;height: 450px;

Пишу скрипт так. Но он не срабатывает как нужно!

```
var inProgress = false;
var startFrom = 42;

$('#loded').scroll(function () {
    if($('#loded').scrollTop() + $('#loded').height() >= $('#loded').height() && !inProgress) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'obrabotchik.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {"startFrom" : startFrom},
            beforeSend: function(data) {inProgress = true;}}).done(function(data){
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function(index,data){
                        $("#loded").append(`<img style='left: 10px;position: relative;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 10px;' class='add' data-id='${data.track}'src='//img.youtube.com/vi/${data.track}/mqdefault.jpg' width='120' height='90'>`);
                        $('.add').on('click', function () {
                            var url = $(this).attr('data-id');
                            var u ="http://www.youtube.com/v/"+url+"?version=3";
                            player.loadVideoByUrl(u);
                            player.unMute();
                        });
                });
                    inProgress = false;
                    startFrom += 42;
            }});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас неправильное условие:

```
$('#loded').scrollTop() + $('#loded').height() >= $('#loded').height()
```

$('#loded').height() будет всегда отдавать 450px, а $('#loded').scrollTop() в нижней точке скролла сначала будет равен 450px, потом 900px, потом 1350px и так далее. 
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
$('#loded').scrollTop() >= $('#loded')[0].scrollHeight - $('#loded').height()
```

Или посмотрите в сторону готовых библиотек.